# Eigen value and rank of a matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

I am as a beginner I want to know is there any relation between eigenvalue and rank of a square matrix 
Please help.

Comment: Yes, see for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349907/what-is-the-relation-between-rank-of-a-matrix-its-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors), or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159232/relationship-rank-of-a-matrix-leftrightarrow-of-eigenvalues?rq=1) etc. The question is perhaps too broad. There are many possible answers (too many).

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of a matrix is the same as the $0$-eigenspace.

The rank of an $m\times n$ matrix is $m$ minus the dimension of kernel.